# Simple way to help an end user to confirm a computer is locked up?

Tags: windows, crash

Occasionally I need to help someone over the phone with a reportedly “frozen” computer.  To avoid corrupting “Something Important™,” I try to avoid having the user pull the power cord unless absolutely necessary.

I usually don’t have physical or remote access to the machine, so I must depend on the user to follow verbal directions then describe what’s happening.

**What can I have the user do to reasonably confirm the computer is truly locked up?**

Comment: On which operating system specifically?  Expecting a specific version of a single operating system.  “all of them” is too broad of a question

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.

Comment: I'd try to setup a script that will do everything that can possibly be done via command line from the security context of the user and ensure they have a script they can click on or type full path of and press `Enter`. Another one may be the `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Esc` for task manager I suppose is useful and if it comes up, then have then type in the script full path from `File` | `Run new Task` and then type in `C:\Scripts\Troubleshoot.cmd` and press `Enter` and then have a file open or something for them to read with whatever you script out, etc.

Comment: That's got to suck not having any access remotely and still have to help them with this problem so you can only do what you can do and then hard boot and sorry if they lost work—lesson learned to save more frequently and be sure to backup critical data.

Comment: @Facebook It's not unusual to receive a call from an user that already has a "frozen" computer that's not in a managed environment. Yes, that sucks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here would be my list:

- The mouse doesn't move and the keyboard is unresponsive. Especially `Ctrl-Alt-Del` which is handled by the kernel.
- The hard drive activity light is solid, without flashing, for an extended period. Or, it is completely idle for an extended period.
- Tapping the power button doesn't cause the system to go in to standby or shutdown.
- When pressing keys on the keyboard the system beeps.
- The system fan turns on full blast in combination with any of the above.
- If working on the same network as the user, the system can't be pinged or can't be connected to remotely with something like PSEXEC if on a domain.
- The video becomes distorted and illegible.

These are just hints of a serious issue. Some would have to be in combination with other, obviously.

Comment: I would add power off/on the monitor to be sure the monitor is still working (if otherwise blank). And/or disconnect/connect the monitor. Add a usb device. Is there a “device” accepted reaction? Does the system even have power? Good luck!

Comment: Another test I use is trying to toggle the caps lock or num lock buttons, the LEDs should toggle when the buttons are pressed, if not then the computer's probably locked up.